# How to use pre-existing Amazon S3 bucket for Artifacts in cdk python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

How to use pre-existing Amazon S3 bucket for source_artifact and cloud_assembly_artifact
[Artifacts docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_codepipeline/Artifact.html#aws_cdk.aws_codepipeline.Artifact) my code is below

```
source_artifact = codepipeline.Artifact()
cloud_assembly_artifact = codepipeline.Artifact()   

pipeline = pipelines.CdkPipeline(self, 'Pipeline',
  cloud_assembly_artifact=cloud_assembly_artifact,
  pipeline_name='testPipeline',
  source_action = cpactions.CodeCommitSourceAction(
            repository=codecommit.Repository.from_repository_name(
              self, 
              id="cicd_pipeline",
              repository_name="repo-name"
            ),
            branch='master',
            action_name='CodeCommit',
            trigger=cpactions.CodeCommitTrigger.POLL,
            output=source_artifact,
        ),
  synth_action=pipelines.SimpleSynthAction(
    source_artifact=source_artifact,
    cloud_assembly_artifact=cloud_assembly_artifact,
    install_command='npm install -g aws-cdk && pip install -r requirements.txt',
    build_command='pytest unittests',
    synth_command='cdk synth'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a codepipeline Pipeline and attach a artifact bucket there.

You can specify a codepipeline in the CdkPipeline construct after you have created the pipeline.
(Typescript but should be similar as python)

```
this._artifactsS3Bucket = Bucket.fromBucketArn(this, 'S3ArtifactsBucket', this._props.s3ArtifactBucketARN);
new Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
      artifactBucket: this._artifactsS3Bucket,
      pipelineName: this._pipelineName,
      restartExecutionOnUpdate: true
});
```

Attach this codePipeline to the construct of the cdkPipeline

Comment: `pipeline = pipelines.CdkPipeline(self, 'Pipeline',
      cloud_assembly_artifact=cloud_assembly_artifact,
      code_pipeline = codepipeline.Pipeline(self, 'Pipeline1',
      artifact_bucket=s3.Bucket.from_bucket_name(self, id="test", bucket_name="bucket-name"),
      restart_execution_on_update=None),
      pipeline_name='testPipeline',`

Comment: I got error after using it.  `  'File "/home/sameed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 326, in send
    raise JSIIError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot set 'pipelineName' if an existing CodePipeline is given using 'codePipeline'`

Comment: you cannot use a pipeline name  in the cdk pipeline construct if you already use a previously created pipeline.

Comment: @SameedUsmani did it work out for you? If see please accept this answer so future users can be helped.

Comment: cdcp = codepipeline.Pipeline(self, 'codepipeline',
      artifact_bucket=bucket,
      restart_execution_on_update=None,
      pipeline_name="cdktestpipeline")